# Alerts not working on SP 2010 on SBS 2011 which also runs Exchange 2010

Tags: alert, iis, exchange-server

we have Sharepoint 2010 & Exchange 2010 on our SBS 2011 server.
I cannot get the alerts to work on SP.
I have followed all the guides I've found without success.
One thing I've noticed is they all say configure SMTP from IIS 6.0 manager which I cannot due to there already being Exchange running on the server i.e. SMTP already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly:

Open the Central Administration site for your SharePoint Foundation.

To do this, on the SBS 2011 server, you click Start | All Programs | Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products | SharePoint 2010 Central Administration

Click "Configuring Outgoing E-mail Settings":

- Outbound SMTP Server: With SBS this is easy enough.  Use the FQDN that will be handling all your requests.  In the case of SBS we are looking at something like `remote.<name of domain>.com`.
- From Address: This is the address that users will see that the email came from for alerts.  It doesn’t even have to be a real address.
- Reply-to Address:  In this case you should indicate an email address that they can reply to.  Note, we used our primary SBS admin in both cases for consistency for the users.
- Character Set: Choose the character set that is appropriate for your language.

Thats should be enough to receive alerts form your SP.

[Use This article for more details](http://www.petri.com/setting-up-sharepoint-email-sbs-2011.htm)

Comment: Wonderful, thanks Robert! It's now working after reading your article. All the articles I read said to config SMTP where your article clarified I didn't/don't need to do this. Thank you again.